# Is it a bad idea do divide the models into directories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a over 100 models in my rails application, and just for organization, I'm dividing them into folders, all still under the main model folder, just to make it simpler to navigate on the project and see files that are related.

Is this a bad idea? What is the rails way to do this?

Comment: Over 100 models? Is it a big project?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

No, it's not a bad idea. Many people do it and I couldn't live without it in large applications.

There are two ways of doing it:

The first is to just move your models. You will, however, have to tell Rails to load the wayward models (as it won't know where they are). Something like this should do the trick:

```
# In config/application.rb
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Other config options

    config.autoload_paths << Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/models/*"]
  end
end
```

The first way is easy, but is not really the best way. The second way involves *namespacing* your models with groups they're in. This means that instead of having `User` and `UserGroup` and `UserPermissions`, you have `User`, `User::Group` and `User::Permission`.

To use this, generate a model like this: `rails generate model User::Group`. Rails will automatically create all of the folders for you. An added benefit is that with this approach, you won't have to spell out the full model name for associations within a namespace:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group # Rails will detect User::Group as it's in the same namespace
end

class User::Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

You can specify however many levels of namespacing as you want, so `User::Group::Permission` would be possible.

Comment: You don't have to add the sub-directories to the load path as app/models is already there. By referencing a nested model such as `User::Group`, Rails will load it automatically by looking in these paths. All `app` constants are eager loaded in production mode.

Comment: @Ryan Yes, if you namespace your models. If you *don't* namespace them but still put them in subfolders, however, and don't add the paths to `config. autoload_paths`, they won't load.

Answer (score 16):

For 100 models, it's practically a requirement. 100 models is noisy in one directory.

Try this to get an idea of the Rails Way (tm)

```
rails new MultiDirectoryExample
cd MultiDirectoryExample
rails generate scaffold User::Photo description:string
```

Watch the script output and view the generated files.