# How to organize large Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture

I am working on a large(ERP level) Rails project. We have 150 tables and more than 150 models. It takes minutes to find a model. Should we add all models under the models folder or should we put them in different subfolders? Same thing goes for controllers and views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621877/is-it-a-bad-idea-do-divide-the-models-into-directories/4621934#4621934) question; with my second example, I talk about namespacing which is possible to do for controllers (and, subsequently, views) as well.

In the case of large applications, I think it would be a very good idea to namespace your models and controllers.

Comment: Thanks. I have been using namespacing but it becomes difficult when declaring associations. You have to declare :foreign_key and :class_name of the association most of the time.

Comment: `:class_name` is common, yes, but I rarely have to specify `:foreign_key` when I use namespacing. However, you could do a combination of both: namespace your controllers and just divide your models into subdirectories (without namespacing).